# Value not getting saved in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have made two models which are as follows:

```
class itemsSearched(models.Model):
  searched_items = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     def __str__(self):  
      return self.searched_items

class VisitorInfo(models.Model):
  user_id         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  items_searched  = models.ManyToManyField(itemsSearched,blank=True)
```

I want to save value tshirt in visitorInfo model. Here is the view for this

```
def get_req(request):
    event = request.GET['e']
    if event == 'pv':

        x_forwarded_for  = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for: 
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        check_user(request,ip)

    elif event == 'pp':
        visitor = VisitorInfo.objects.get(user_id=request.GET['duid'])
        visitor.active = True
        print(visitor.active)
        visitor.save()

    elif event == 'ue':
        u_id    = request.GET['duid']
        tz      = request.GET['tz']
        url     = request.GET['url']
        link    = request.GET['ue_pr'] #ue_pr is the property of unstructured event of the type json.
        o       = json.loads(link)
        print(o)

        if(o['data']['data']['elementId']=='nf-field-1'):
            name = o['data']['data']['value']
            print("Name: "+ name)
            visitor= VisitorInfo.objects.get(user_id=u_id)
            visitor.name = name
            visitor.save()

        elif(o['data']['data']['elementId']=='s'):
            searched_item = int(o['data']['data']['value'])
            print("Searched: "+ searched_item) #6
            print("Type of searched_item " + type(searched_item)) #7
            visitor= VisitorInfo.objects.get(user_id=u_id)
            visitor.items_searched.add(searched_item)
            visitor.save()
```

For the sake of clarity I printed 'o' which is a python dictionary parsed from json.Here is the what i have got

```
{'schema': 'iglu:com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/unstruct_event/jsonschema/1-0-0', 'data': {'schema': 'iglu:com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/change_form/jsonschema/1-0-0', 'data': {'formId': 'FORM', 'elementId': 's', 'nodeName': 'INPUT', 'type': 'search', 'elementClasses': ['search-field'], 'value': 'tshirt'}}}
```

I want to save the value 'tshirt' in visitor info but i am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site- packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 243, in process_exception_by_middleware
    return super(AsgiHandler, self).process_exception_by_middleware(exception, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/dashboard/views.py", line 411, in get_req
    visitor.items_searched.add(searched)
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 934, in add
    self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1083, in _add_items
    '%s__in' % target_field_name: new_ids,
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 784, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 802, in _filter_or_exclude
   clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1261, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1217, in build_filter
    condition = lookup_class(lhs, value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 56, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 56, in <listcomp>
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]
  File "/home/ubuntu/awsupload/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 966, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tshirt'
```

Output of print statement at #6 is as below

```
Searched: tshirt
```

Output of print statement at #7 is as below

```
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, you can't add a string to a many-to-many field. You need to an object of the related model.

I haven't quite understood what you're trying to do, but I suspect you want to get or create an ItemSearched model for "t-shirt", and then add that.

```
item, _ = itemsSearched.objects.get_or_create(searched_items=searched_item)
visitor = VisitorInfo.objects.get(user_id=u_id)
visitor.items_searched.add(item)
```

Note, you don't need to save `visitor` after only modifying its m2m field.